# java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to run the below program,using the hadoop-3.0.1. I have imported the 
  hadoop-client-api-3.0.1.jar,hadoop-client-runtime-3.0.1.jar
and hadoop-client-minicluster-3.0.1.jar
 :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class HDFSFileTest {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    try {
        String fileName="test.txt";
        Configuration conf =new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://localhost:9000");
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl","org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
        FileSystem fs=FileSystem.get(conf);     
        if(fs.exists(new Path(fileName))) {
            System.out.println("File exists!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File not exists!");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I get the excetpion in eclipse:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$GetFileInfoRequestProto cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:225)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:876)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1619)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1494)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1506)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1668)
```

Comment: Did you install Hadoop 3.0.1? Does `hdfs fs -ls` work?

Comment: It works,but i didn't configure the enviroment variable of hadoop,i need to change directory to make it work.

Comment: Which environment variable? If that command doesn't work by itself, then you must make yourself a user directory

Comment: The PATH, but I run the code in eclipse and import revelent jars, does  the enviroment variable of hadoop matter?

Comment: It should. Otherwise, only the defaults for HADOOP_CONF_DIR will be used. However, I suspect your JAR files are not the same version as the cluster itself. I also recommend that you use Maven or Gradle instead of manually adding jars yourself

Comment: I choose to use hadoop 2.7.5 instead 3.0.1， the problem solved,thank you.

Comment: The issue seems to be due to mismatch of Hadoop versions shaded with the JAR and the runtime environment. Removing the `<dependency>` blocks related to `hadoop` from `pom.xml` will enable to select the correct version from the hadoop runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this when trying to use pyarrow to access hdfs.. make sure you're using the correct non-deprecated connect method to prevent hadoop version issues

```
hdfs = fs.HadoopFileSystem('hostname', 8020)
```

NOT

```
fs = pa.hdfs.connect('hostname')
```